# How to add local dependencies in buildr

Tags: java, scala, buildr

For a java/scala project I have some dependencies that are not in a remote repository, but somewhere else in my filesystem. I have then two options, which lead to questions:

1. I can add a `lib/` directory in my project folder. How can I tell buildr to add the content to the class path ?
2. I can use the builtin dependencies management system. Can I indicate a filesystem repository path instead of an http one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution I was looking for in `buildr` mailing list. The `compile.with()` method accepts an array of file names (with the path prefix of course). So if the dependencies are jars in a directory called `lib` you can just call:

```
compile.with Dir['lib/*.jar']
```

in the `buildfile`. Hope that will help other `buildr` adepts.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself!

Comment: 'lib/**/*.jar' will get you subfolder of lib as well

Comment: Thanks @paradigmatic and @Sebastian! Just what I needed. Has anyone found good "recipes" for buildr? The manual is nice, but I find it short on real examples. Although, to be fair, most things are very simple in buildr so you don't really need a lot of tweaking.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your second question:

> I can use the builtin dependencies management system. Can I indicate a
>   filesystem repository path instead of an http one ?

Yes, just like maven2, you can use the file:/// protocol to locate a "remote" repository on the file system.